# How many workspaces should be taken - Poisson?

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-distribution

The following scenario:

Customers come to the center and get in touch with the information and wait until they are called from the waiting area. (As with the doctor, for example)

- Customers should not wait more than 10 minutes. This maximum waiting time varies from day to day. This means that more waiting time can be calculated on Monday than on Friday, for example. Always 100% of the customers are processed.
- We know when the customers arrive and how long the average processing time is.
- There is a workstation limitation: that is, if only 6 workstations are available, only 6 workstation can be occupied to the maximum. If only 6 workstations are available, only these 6 can be scheduled at maximum. This number is also variable.

**So the goal is**: how many workstations should be occupied (per interval) so that the maximum waiting time for a customer is met.

The following information is available to us per interval (15 minutes):

- Max. workspaces per interval
- Customer volume and average processing time per interval

How do you calculate this best? Does a Poisson distribution make sense here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The processing time is assumed constant ? How does it compare to the "interval" time ? What imposes the "interval" time ?

Comment: Hi @cladelpino, For each interval, there is a value for the processing time and a value for the customer volume. These are not constant but simply average values. If we assume that we have 24 hours open, we have 96 intervals per day. For each of these 96 intervals, as indicated above, we have a numeric value for the average processing time and a numerical value for the (expected) customer volume.

Comment: ok, so the interval time is fixed at 15 mins. Are the average processing times less, more or both than this ?

Comment: @cladelpino the average processing time can be both.

Comment: @cladelpino so do you have no idea? The whole should be solved with the [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory)

Comment: Isn't this your case ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue

Answer (score 0):

This calculator can be used to analyze each period, that, as far as I can see, fits the [M/M/c queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/c_queue) model:

https://www.supositorio.com/rcalc/rcalclite.htm

Of course, you can implement the formulas in any software and automate the finding of the number of workstations for each period.